# How to allow a column in Compose to go beyond the screen boundaries - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple parent column with no modifiers, which can contain a similar child column also with no modifiers. The problem is that instead of going beyond the screen boundaries, the child column and its elements are either violating the paddings or even reducing the number of elements. I would like them to simply go off the screen.

All possible mods and variants

Comment: why not use Lazy Column

Comment: If your element is limited then you can use ```verticalScroll``` modifier of column to make it scrollable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ChiragThummar it cant be scrollable, design :(

Comment: @Raghunandan it cant be Lazy Column, i dont need scrollable logic

Comment: @KamogawaRoar Make your question clear. you are denying all that I don't want scrollable. So what you want explain it properly

Comment: @KamogawaRoar if it goes beyond screen boundaries and if its not scrollable how will user be able to view the data on screen?

Comment: @Raghunandan the design assumes that if elements do not fit into the screen, they should go beyond its borders, but user cant scroll interface. Whole Ui its just skeleton with shimmer animation.

Comment: You need to increase maxHeight constraints coming from parent as in my answer. By default Child Composable gets height of parent as maxHeight of `Constraints`. If you change it to Constraints.Infinity you can measure your child Column as big as its content is. vertical scroll modifier does this under the hood  as LazyLists. Measuring something with infinite upper bounds let's it be as big as it required. Of, course you can also override this behavior too but it's an answer for another question.

Answer (score 1):

Column measures children with maximum.height, by default it's not possible to go above maximum height in Constraints but there are several ways to override this behavior.

Basically you need to measure child Column with maxHeight Constraints.Infinity to have it height bigger than parent. You can use `Modifier.wrapContentHeight(unbounded=true, alignment=Alignment.Top)` or use Modifier.layout or a custom Layout to increase maxHeight to `Constraints.Infinity`.

In the sample below i set height of parent 100.dp to fit screen with other samples but in your case you can set it fillmaxSize or fillmaxHeight

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ConstraintsSample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Text("Original")
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Red)
        ) {
            Column(
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Yellow)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
        Text("Modifier.wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true)")

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Red)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(
                    align = Alignment.Top,
                    unbounded = true
                )
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Yellow)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
        Text("Modifier.layout")

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Red)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                        val placeable = measurable.measure(
                            constraints.copy(maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity)
                        )
                        layout(
                            constraints.maxWidth, placeable.height
                        ) {
                            val yPos = (placeable.height - constraints.maxHeight) / 2
                            placeable.placeRelative(0, yPos)
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Yellow)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In second and third one by setting Constraints.Infinity implicitly or explicitly we let child Column to have the height it actually requires which is 150.dp. In first sample parent Column limits child Column height to 100.dp as default.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the child column and its elements go off the screen instead of violating paddings or reducing the number of elements, you can use the Modifier.fillMaxSize() modifier in combination with a ScrollableColumn. Here's how you can achieve this.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun ParentColumnWithScrollableChild() {
    // Create a scroll state to make the child column scrollable
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize() // Fills the entire available screen size
            .padding(16.dp) // Optional padding for the parent column
    ) {
        // Parent Column
        // You can add any content you want here

        // Scrollable Child Column
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp), // Optional padding for the child column
            state = scrollState
        ) {
            // Add your child elements here
            items(100) { index ->
                // Child element
                // You can add any content for child elements here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here we use a LazyColumn for the child column, which allows for efficient recycling of items and scrolling when there are many elements. The Modifier.fillMaxSize() on the parent column ensures it takes up the entire screen space, and the Modifier.fillMaxWidth() on the child column makes sure it occupies the full width of the parent column. The rememberScrollState is used to manage the scroll position of the child column.

Now, if the child column's content exceeds the screen boundaries, it will become scrollable, allowing you to scroll through the elements without violating paddings or reducing the number of elements displayed.

Comment: i cant use LazyColumn, it cant be scrollable

Comment: Can you explain in detail? How can't you use LazyColumn?